# Email not sent or not working?

Tags: php, email

I need to ask a simple question to anyone. Any clue will be much appreaciated!

Could you please tell me any reason why a php mail() may not be sent?

I am pretty sure all details entered are correct from $to to $headers etc.

Please, Francesco

Code is:

```
<?php  
if (array_key_exists('sendEmail', $_POST)) {


    $to = 'my@email.com,'.$_POST['email'].''; 

    $subject = 'bla bla';  

    $headers = 'From: my@email.com>\r\n"  

        ."Reply-To: $email';  

    $message = 'Dear '.$_POST['name']."\r\n\r\n"; 

    $message .= 'Your Booking Number is '.$_POST['ID']."\r\n";  

    $message .= 'Name ' .$_POST['title']. ' ' .$_POST['firstname']. ' ' .$_POST['lastname']."\r\n";  



    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers); 

}
```

?>

Comment: it would probably be helpful if you posted the code in question...

Comment: Does it error out? Does PHP have mail support compiled in on that machine (you should be able to tell via phpinfo())? And where are you testing this, on your local machine or a web server?

Comment: Probably depends on the server, most of them (if you're using a hosting provider) don't allow sending mail to external domains.

Comment: it does not give any error. It all seems ok and It goes to next page. It is on a web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enclosing the mail() method:

```
if(mail(...)) {
   echo "SUCCESS";
} else {
   echo "FAILURE";
}
```

The mail method will return false if transmission failed.

Comment: Hi matias f
I have tried what you said. What happens is that at the top of the page appears: "email not sent" of the else stetement I set up, before I press any button. Can this be a clue?